# jQuery not multiplying numbers correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Im trying to use some jQuery functions to multiply the values of two `number_field`'s in rails.

My jQuery code is this:

```
$('#mycometer_coc_sample_bv1').change(function() {
  $('#cv').empty();
  var BV1 = $('#mycometer_coc_sample_bv1').val();
  var BV2 = $('#mycometer_coc_sample_bv2').val();
  $('#mycometer_coc_sample_cv').val( ( BV2 - BV1 )*0.84 + BV2 );
  $('#cv').append( $('#mycometer_coc_sample_cv').val() );
});

$('#mycometer_coc_sample_bv2').change(function() {
  $('#cv').empty();
  var BV1 = $('#mycometer_coc_sample_bv1').val();
  var BV2 = $('#mycometer_coc_sample_bv2').val();
  $('#mycometer_coc_sample_cv').val( ( BV2 - BV1 )*0.84 + BV2 );
  $('#cv').append( $('#mycometer_coc_sample_cv').val() );
});
```

`#mycometer_coc_sample_cv` is a hidden number_field used to send the value back to my controller. Im displaying that value into a div of `#cv`

The first function works correctly. The examples numbers I've been using are BV1 = 2, BV2 = 12. When entering 2 into BV1 I get the correct output into CV of -1.68, But when entering the second value 12 into BV2 I get 8.412, when the correct output should be 20.4

I have no idea whats going wrong. 
Can anyone help debug this?

Some screenshots:
Entering first value = correct output
[image]

Second value something goes wrong and incorrect output. CV should equal 20.4

(12-2) = 10 => 10*0.84 = 8.4 => 8.4 + 12 = 20.4
[image]

Comment: jQuery doesn't do multiplication. That's JavaScript. And understand that the return value from `.val()` is always a **string**, so you have to force it to be a number explicitly.

Comment: And it is done in the browser ... which knows nothing about what server language or framework you use. Rails is irrelevant

Comment: I did not know `.val()` returned string. After wrapping my variables in `Number()` that gave me the correct output

Answer (score 2):

Becase `input`'s `val()` method returns a string, you need to call `parseInt()` on the values like:

```
var BV1 = parseInt($('#mycometer_coc_sample_bv1').val(), 10);
```

Otherwise these values will not be added. They will be concatenated as a strings. So:

```
'12' + '2' === '122'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my comment above I mentioned that wrapping my variables `BV1` and `BV2` in `Number(BV1)` gave me the correct output.

Comment: Yes, `Number()` could be a solution as well.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the OP is working with real numbers and `parseInt()` is for integers. Either `parseFloat()` or the `Number()` constructor or more simply the `+` unary prefix operator might be better solutions.

Comment: By default `<input type="number" />` doesn't allow float numbers. This is why I suggested `parseInt`. Of course, if one needs floats, `parseFloat()` would be better, for instance.